# select one of multiple rows generated by a join based on certain column

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Alright say I have a tickets table, users table, roles table, and role_mapping table.  A ticket is owned by a user. A user can have 1 or multiple roles.  The roles table defines roles, while the role_mapping table maps a user to his/her roles (roles are basically permissions).  So what I want to do is join users, tickets, and role_mapping as such (Oracle SQL):

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, u.user_id, rm.role_id
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
JOIN role_mappings rm on rm.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE ...
```

So this of course generates multiple rows with the same ticket_id if a given user has multiple roles.  What I want is if the role_id is say '102', only generate one row with value '102', otherwise, generate only one row corresponding to the maximum role value a given user has ie, if a user has role_id 101,102,105 then select 102, but if 101,105 then select 105.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake in your example (102 picked when you have 101,102,105 doesn't align with your written description) - but what you are looking for is `group by` after your joins and using an aggregate function (`max`) to pick your maximum value role. Something like:

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, u.user_id, max(rm.role_id)
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
JOIN role_mappings rm on rm.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY t.ticket_id, u.user_id
```

If you want all the roles in one line check out `GROUP_CONCAT`

**UPDATE**

To meet the requirement of role `102` taking precedence one way would be to exclude results which have ticket-users with role 102 and then adding them in in a second query using `union`

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, u.user_id, max(rm.role_id)
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
JOIN role_mappings rm on rm.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (
     SELECT t.ticket_id, u.user_id, max(rm.role_id)
     FROM tickets t
     JOIN users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
     JOIN role_mappings rm on rm.user_id = u.user_id
     WHERE rm.role_id = 102)
GROUP BY u.id

UNION ALL 

SELECT t.ticket_id, u.user_id, rm.role_id
FROM tickets t
JOIN users u on u.user_id = t.user_id
JOIN role_mappings rm on rm.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE rm.role_id=102
```

Fiddle here without the tickets table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc1c6/5

Comment: Ahh the mistake I was making was quite simple actually.  I already had group by there, but I was including rm.role_id in the group by clause.  removing it then only gives the max value.
Now, having said that, I only want to do the max value if a user does not have role_id 102.  If he/she does have 102, I want to ignore any higher values and use that.  What would you do for that?

Comment: For logic like that you will need to use a case statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: or a different subquery for records with and without the `roleId` 102

Comment: It will however be a more complex query than what you are asking here. If you don't get it yourself I would ask a new question with better details and a SQL Fiddle like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc1c6/1 Basically you want this query except when the user has role 102.

Comment: Basically I'm just having trouble visualizing just how to include the case statement into what is already about a page long query.  It seems that within the case statement, I would have to re-execute the entire base query except only selecting role_id. Is that correct? I could post my entire current query, but I thought it would just serve to complicate things given that most of it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: The question re-asked is going to look like an exact duplicate, is that allowed?

Comment: Yes - nevermind - I see that you did ask clearly and I misread. I will try and help you later. In the meantime perhaps you'll get another answer.

Comment: Alright that looks like it will work. I'll get back to you once I've cajoled it into my query.  Union never even crossed my mind.

Comment: Just a couple of FYIs, I used 't.ticket_id not in' since a given user can have any number of tickets. Also, the order by/group by structure had to be as such:
`select *
from(query
group by (everything selected)
union all
second query
group by (everything selected))
order by`